# Unexpected changes in std::vector

Tags: c++, struct, stdvector

Here is the code:

```
typedef struct Triplet
{
    double value;
    int row;
    int column;
};

class Matrix
{
public:
//Some methods
double specialMethod(/*params*/);
private:
    std::vector<Triplet> elements;
    int nRows;
    int nColumns;
};
```

After `specialMethod` gets called values in Matrix.element are corrupted. But there is nothing done with them except for iterating like this:

```
std::vector<Triplet>::iterator it;
std::vector<Pair> buff;
for (it = this->elements.begin(); it != this->elements.end(); ++it)
    {

        if (it->column = n)
        { 
            Pair p;
            p.key = it->row;
            p.value = it->value;
            buff.push_back(p);
        }
    }
```

Don't have any idea where to start looking for mistake.

Comment: You could start by turning on compiler warnings and fix the issue it points out, which is probably the cause of the problem

Comment: In Visual Studio if you set warning level above 3, compiler will warn about assignment in condition. Good way to start next time.

Comment: kotlomoy & Jonathan, thanks, will use next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  if (it->column = n)
```

should be:

```
 if (it->column == n)
```

You are doing comparison not assignment.

Comment: Will approve the answer in 12 minutes, SO don't let me do it right now.

Comment: @PavelOganesyan thank a lot for accepting the answer if it does solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

If it's possible, define n as a const value and invert order in comparison inside if instruction - just like that: if(n == it->column). 
Compiler will help you to find similar bugs.

Please note that compilers warn about this kind of error anyway if higher warning levels are turned on.